# Expected value of $E(X-Y|X+Y)$ if $X \sim Y$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

If we have two discret random values with $X \sim Y$, prove that
$$E(X-Y|X+Y)=0$$
My first try was to do this
$$E(X-Y) =E(X)-E(Y)=0$$
In other hand
$$E(X-Y)=\sum_{z} E(X-Y|X+Y=z)P(X+Y=z)$$
I don't know what to do.

Comment: Does “$X \sim Y$” mean $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed, though not necessarily independent of each other?

Comment: Yes, no necessarily independent just that P(X=x)=P(Y=x)

Comment: When you say $\mathbb{E}[X- Y | X+Y]$ do you want a random variable?

Comment: Inspired by @lonza leggiera's solution, I believe if both X and Y are binary (can take only two values), then the claim is true.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Being $X\sim Y$ it is also $X|(X+Y)\sim Y|(X+Y)$

thus

$$\mathbb{E}[X-Y|X+Y]=\mathbb{E}[X|X+Y]-\mathbb{E}[Y|X+Y]=0$$

Comment: I  believe this is not necessarily true unless $\ X\ $ and $\ Y\ $ are independent.

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe the statement to be necessarily true unless $\ X\ $ and $\ Y\ $ are independent.

Suppose the joint distribution of $\ X\ $ and $\ Y\ $ is given by the following array, the entry in row $\ i\ $ and column $\ j\ $ being $\ P(X=i,Y=j)\ $.
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
&1&2&3\\
\hline
1&\frac{1}{20}&\frac{2}{20}&\frac{3}{20}\\
2&\frac{5}{20}&\frac{2}{20}&\frac{1}{20}\\3&0&\frac{4}{20}&\frac{2}{20}
\end{array}
$$
The distributions of $\ X\ $ and $\ Y\ $ are the same, with probability mass vector $\ \big(\frac{3}{10},\frac{2}{5},\frac{3}{10}\big)\ $. However,
\begin{align}
E(X-Y|X+Y=3)&=\frac{3}{7}\\
E(X-Y|X+Y=4)&={-}\frac{6}{5}\\
E(X-Y|X+Y=5)&=\frac{3}{5}\ .
\end{align}